# How do I avoid crashing while freeing cv::Mat in countNonZero?

Tags: opencv

I am seeing a crash in a very simple code snippet. The crash occurs when cv::Mat::deallocate attempts to free unallocated memory. I even simplified the code ride down to the point where it is useless, but I still see the crash.

```
boost::shared_ptr<cv::Mat> mask = ...;
cv::Mat thresholdedImage = cv::Mat::zeros(mask->size(), CV_32FC1);
cv::Mat dummyMask = cv::Mat::zeros(mask->size(), CV_32FC1);
cv::threshold(dummyMask, thresholdedImage, 0.5, 1, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
int nonzeroCount = cv::countNonZero(thresholdedImage);
```

Here is the backtrace:

```
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93aa49a3 abort + 129
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff92ec91cb free + 428
3   MyLib.dylib                     0x0000000135b45d7c cv::StdMatAllocator::deallocate(cv::UMatData*) const + 60
4   MyLib.dylib                     0x0000000135b0240c cv::Mat::deallocate() + 28
5   MyLib.dylib                     0x0000000135ba9362 cv::countNonZero(cv::_InputArray const&) + 802
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete example please?

Comment: Usually this is caused by linking to the wrong libraries (different compiler, different architecture, debug vs release). But also the shared pointer to the `Mat` is suspicious... Don't do that! `Mat` are already _smart pointers_